# When will the population reach 20,000?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

A bacteria culture initially contains 500 cells and grows a rate proportional to its size. After an hour the population has increased to 1200.

a). Find the expression for the number of bacteria after t hours.
**Answer: k= 0.014591146** because

1200= 500$e^(k*60)$

divide by 1200/500 and then do ln|| on both sides to get k.

b) Find the number of bacteria after 4 hours?
P(240)= 500$e^(0.014591146*240)$

**Answer: 16,588**

c) Find the rate of growth.

dy/dt= 0.014591146*16588= 242/60 = **4.03 cells/hr**

d) When will the population reach 20,000?

The way I went about this is: 
$$20,000 = 500e^{0.014591146\,t}$$

which turned into $\ln|40|= \ln|e^{0.014591146\,t}|$

*The $\ln|e^x|$ cancels so I am left with

$$\frac{\ln|40|}{0.014591146} =t$$

My answer came out to be **252 years**? However my professor said my answer was incorrect? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the units of $k$?

Comment: Maybe, he only meant that the correct rounding gives $253$ years ?

Comment: Would you mind posting the whole exercise ? This would make it easier to see whether the given equation is correct. It is solved correctly, ignoring the rounding.

Comment: That's probably it because when I plug 252 into the P(t)= 500$e^(0.014591146*252)$ = 19764 cells. @Peter

Comment: If we are talking of cells I think that the right unit is not year. Please let us know the units of $k$.

Comment: So, you would have to round up anyway , if I understand the exercise right. Even if the result would have been , lets say, $250.1$

Comment: @Peter I updated it. Yeah for some reason I was marked off  for part d; no partial credit what-so-ever.

Comment: @Peter so I would divide 253 by 60, right?

Comment: A moment, the unit is minutes. Yes, you have to divide by $60$ to get the hours.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see why I was marked incorrectly. @Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem says that initially there are 500 cells and after an hour the population has increased to 1200. To find $k= 0.014591146$ you plug $t=60$ so $k$ is measured in 1/minute. The precise result t=252.81629380680148789220913131845 is the number of MINUTES not YEARS.

Answer (score 0):

Using your Maths, we get:

$$t=252.81629380680148789220913131845$$

and this should be the answer.

If we round to years, we need the population to **exceed** $20,000$, and $252$ falls short, only yielding $19764$, and so we need $253$ years.

Comment: So the process of how I went about getting the answer is correct? The only thing I messed up on was my rounding?

Comment: well yeah, but after 252 years you haven't **exceeded** 20,000 so your answer was wrong